# Jackson запаковал Map с объектами в JSON неверно

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Использую Spring MVC 4.
Отправил из метода контроллера вот такую карту:

```
Map<Coordinates, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

класс-ключ простой. Два примитива int и всё. Отправил эту карту клиенту как ответ на его запрос.

`return new ResponseEntity<>(map, HttpStatus.OK);`

В итоге клиенту пришла вот это:

```
    {"x: 7, y: 9;":"/images/alive_deck.jpg",
"x: 6, y: 9;":"/images/alive_deck.jpg"}
```

Как видно ключ в данном случае вовсе не объект, а строка. `"x: 7, y: 9;"` - это получилось изза того что был вызван метод toString у класса Coordinates. Как мне заставить запаковывать в строку нормально? или это невозможно?

Comment: Ну конечно нужно Rest контроллер сделать и указать что методы json возвращают. Можно тут поглядеть: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060060/spring-rest-not-returning-my-object-json

Comment: причём тут REST? кстати вот чего я хотел. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11634031/2604639

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В JSON ключом может быть только строка. Что вы хотите получить в качестве ключа? Что значит "запаковывать в строку нормально"?
Jackson поступил совершенно правильно. Ему для ключа нужна строка - он и получил её, вызвав toString у вашего объекта типа Coordinates.